# Is this a typo in Weibel, page 1?

Tags: modules, homological-algebra

It says a morphism $u : C_{\cdot } \to D_{\cdot}$ of chain complexes is a family of homomorphisms $u_n : C_n \to D_n$ such that $u_{n-1} d_n = d_{n-1} u_{n}$, but shouldn't it just be that $u_{n-1} d_n = d_n u_{n}$?  I want to make sure my understanding of the differentials $d$ is correct before moving on.

Comment: @paulgarrett  Thanks.   But I need you to change that probably into a definite thing.  :D

Comment: Ok, let's agree first that the real point is that all the squares commute, in the diagram expressing a map from the one complex to the other. If I think carefully, then what you quoted is (most likely) correct, assuming that I correctly guess the notation: the upper and lower edges of the square are _both_ $d_n$ (but from different complexes), the left edge is $u_n$, and the right edge is $u_{n-1}$. (Or reverse left-and-right.) Maybe our intuitive type-checking in the notation needs the $d_n$'s for the two complexes to have different names, and that might be what cause some reaction in you.

Comment: Also, I think the number of typos in Weibel's book, after going through the list of errata on his home page at Rutgers (which catches many typos as well as a few more serious things), is smallish. Still, yes, eternal vigilance is required in indexing schemes... Better, by far, to "look at the picture" (=diagram) rather than fooling with shifting indices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is written in the text is an error. The composition $d_{n-1}u_n$ doesn't make sense since $u_n:C_n\to D_n$ and $d_{n-1}:D_{n-1}\to D_{n-2}$. It should be $d_nu_n$. The convention is that the index of the map should match the index on the domain. It's often easier, as sometimes done in that book, just to write $ud = du$ and omit the indices altogether.

The error is also already written in his 1995 version errata sheet. If you have the paper copy I just recommend fixing the errors in each chapter before you read it.